# De Morgan's Laws and General Probability

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

On my textbook, it says that

$A' \land B' = (A \lor B)' \implies Pr[(A \lor B)'] = Pr(A' \land B')$

Is the converse also true? That is,

$Pr[(A \lor B)'] = Pr(A' \land B') \implies A' \land B' = (A \lor B)'$

Now I know that the second implication is false.

If we denote X = $(A \lor B)'$, and Y = $(A' \land B')$, then the second implication is saying that

Pr(X) = Pr(Y) $\implies$ X = Y, which is clearly false.

Thank you all for helping!

Comment: $A'\wedge B'=(A\vee B)'$ is **on its own** a true statement. So if we denote it by $q$ then statements like $p\implies q$ are always true. There is no reason to make this explicit for e.g. the statement $p$ that you mention.

Comment: In general, that two events have the same probability does not *logically entail* that they are the same event.  So any demonstration that $\mathsf P((A\cup B)') = \mathsf P(A'\cap B')$ is not *on its own* a proof for deMorgan's rule.  However, in the specific case where $X=Y$ then the *material implication* $\mathsf P(X)=\mathsf P(Y)\to X=Y$ clearly holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define two different symbols
\begin{align}
X &= A′∧B′\\
Z &= (A∨B)′
\end{align}
deMorgan's law now states that 
$$X = Z$$
no matter what. Hence, it is obvious that also $P(X) = P(Z)$, because we just renamed $X$.

In order to take a different point of view, let's consider a "standard function" instead of a probability:

- The probability $P(.)$ is a function which maps an "event X" onto a "number P(X)". Instead, we consider a function $f(y) = y^2$ which maps a "number $y$" onto an other "number $f(y)$". Now   suppose we write
  \begin{align}
  X &= 2\\
  Z &= 3-1
  \end{align}
  Since, $X=Z$ we will always get $P(X) = P(Z) = 2^2 = 4$.
- However, since $f(-2) = f(2)$ we can *not* conclude that $-2 = 2$. Hence, in the "probability world" $P(N) = P(M)$ does *not* imply $N = M$.

Comment: Thank you! I shouldn't use the De Morgan's Laws which makes the problem unnecessarily unclear. What I'm asking is that is the probability function onto? That is, does P(N) = P(M) imply N=M for M, N are sets.

Comment: As I tried to point out, $P(N)=P(M)$ does  _not_ imply $N=M$. Just take the upper example or ... Suppose we flip a coin. Therefore, we have only two possible outcomes $X \elem \{0,1\}$. Each  has  the chance $P(X=0) = 1/2 = P(X=1)$. Now we have $P(X=0) = P(X=1)$ however we clearly have $X = 1 \ne 0$.

Answer (score 2):

The second part of the second implication is always true for De Morgan law. 
Moreover if two sets have the same probability it doesn't mean they are the same! I don't understand what you mean with the second question. Probability obviously uses set theory.